QGIS creating 4 offset points from a set of points
I work with a lot of projects where I have point shapefiles where the points are in a line that is not always straight.
I have been wanting to find a way for a while now to create offsets from these points that are:
A: equal distance to the center point and,
B: the off set points being two on the left and two on the right of the line of points.
Is this possible for a newbie?

